# Spring REST - @createdDate in Abstract superclass throws error

Tags: java, spring, audit, spring-rest

i´m having trouble with Spring REST (new to it).

My intention is to have an Abstract-Super-Class with some common fields like ID/Version/CreatedDate and soon more.
It works just fine with JPA and database wise. But when i try to expose a child with some Repository `PagingAndSortingRepository` i get the following error once i query the api.

Other fields work just fine. Its something corresponding to the @CreatedDate annotation.

**Error:**

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution:        
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
Could not write JSON: java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
java.sql.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String (through reference chain: 
org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources["_embedded"]-
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap["users"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$PersistentEntityResourceSerializer$1["content"]->com.*.*.domain.User["createdDate"])
```

**Super:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractPersistentObject
    implements PersistentObject, Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
protected Long id;
protected Integer version;

@org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
public Date createdDate;

... getter / setter / constructor

protected Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

protected void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}
```

**Example child:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserTable")
public class User extends AbstractPersistentObject {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
@JsonIgnore
private String password;

private boolean verified;
...
```

---

**Solution:**

```
Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.0.0.M2 to 2.0.0.M3.
```

Comment: The error indicates a data type conversion problem. Please include the getter and setter for `createdDate` from `AbstractPersistentObject`.

Comment: i included the getter setter for that field. Thx for the reply

Comment: Do you have the annotation `@EnableJpaAuditing` somewhere in your project?

Comment: Yes, i had the createdDate annotation working. They work whenever they are in the child class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support.

exceptionally i didnt mess up! I currently work with Spring boot 2.0.0.M2. I updated to 2.0.0.M3 and it just works.

I shortly looked into the repo but did not find anything regarding us.

**Solution:**

```
Upgrading Spring Boot from 2.0.0.M2 to 2.0.0.M3.
```

Should have checked this earlier, since it is somehow expected while working with this versions!

Comment: Good to know that you resolved the problem. Shame on me for not asking for version information. I just assumed that you were using a stable version and not a milestone release.

Comment: Yeah - i should have mentioned that in the first place. Its just a project for learning purposes, so i thought it would be fine ... :)

Answer (score 0):

In class `AbstractPersistentObject`, instance variable `createdDate` is declared *public* whereas the getter and setter are declared *protected*. Try reversing the access so that the getter and setter are *public* and the instance variable is *protected* (or private).

Comment: Yes, i played with thoose already. Thanks for the reply, i solved it by upgrading Spring Boot.

Answer (score -1):

try use @CreatedDate from package: `org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate`

Comment: i checked it. Sadly its the correct one, but i didnt make sure before ^^